Regarding compilation error "Did not find entry for byfmt=pdflatex"
I am compiling a document using texlive. When compiling, I receive the following error notification:

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "id_infinite".tex


kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt


mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):


mktexfmt: /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes: mktexfmt: /home/hitesh/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf


mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/hitesh/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c


mktexfmt [INFO]: Did not find entry for byfmt=pdflatex skipped mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 8 mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 8


mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0


Process exited with error(s)

Any solution is appreciated.

You are using a local configuration /home/hitesh/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf  avoid doing that and always use fmtutil-sys (not fmtutil-user) to make formats unless you know you need the latter

I had a similar issue and solved it by completing my LaTeX installation. On Manjaro I had to install:
sudo pacman -S extra/texlive-latex extra/texlive-latexextra extra/texlive-plaingeneric extra/texlive-fontsrecommended 

